# C# JSON String Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

I am really struggling to find any examples of JSON Deserialization in C# where the first property in each JSON item is a different ID.

```
    {
       "12112083":{
           "Topic_ID":"12112083",
           "Moved_ID":"51",
           "subject":"subject text goes here"      
           },
       "12111966":{
           "Topic_ID":"12111966",
           "Moved_ID":"51",
           "subject":"another subject text"      
           },
       "12106917":{
           "Topic_ID":"12106917",
           "Moved_ID":"0",
           "subject":"test"      
           }
    }
```

I have tried a few different methods without success.  The JSON returned which I have no control of is sometimes a single item and sometimes an array of items like the example above. Ideally I would like to deserialize into a typed object class if possible.

Thanks

Thanks L.B

I have tried the code sample provided passing the following string

```
    '{"12112083":{"Topic_ID":"12112083","Moved_ID":"51","subject":"Due to a computer virus, many of my files are \u005C"Crypted\u005C",espe","Start_date":"10/6/2012 6:54:37 PM","InitialResponseDueDate":"10/6/2012 7:01:37 PM","Locked":"0","QValue":"$10","Status":"1","Author_ID":"71318191","Question_Text":"Due to a computer virus, many of my files are \u005C"Crypted\u005C",especially my pictures.  Now my FinepixA500 camera will not upload photos to my computer (laptop).  Geek Squad could not crack the code and suggested that I contact Toshiba and have them reset the computer to its original manufacturer settings.  If I do that, I will lose all of my data.  The only thing that appears not to be working is \u005C"photo gallery\u005C". (therefore, my camera will not upload photos anymore.....) Any suggestions?","Username":"JACUSTOMER-iei7o0tr-","No_of_Questions":"0","No_of_Accepts":"0","Last_visit":"10/6/2012 7:22:18 PM","Join_Date":"10/6/2012 6:46:29 PM","lastExpert":"","IsPress":"False","hasCustomerOptOuts":"0","RecCount":"0","OptedOut":"","Urgency":"51","AuthorHasSubscription":"False","Relisted":"0","IsAbandoned":"False","categoryName":"Camera and Video","categoryName_Additional":"Laptop","QuestionCommissionHasAdjusted":"False","LockedBy":"-1","IsOnline":"False","QuestionLink":"/video-camera-repair/77lqr-due-computer-virus-files-crypted-espe.html","WaitingForYou":"False","RequestedForYou":"False","IsChatEnabled":"False","ChangedKeyList":"","DeltaType":"A"},"12111966":{"Topic_ID":"12111966","Moved_ID":"51","subject":"office/outlook for mac 2011 keeps hanging upMicrosoft Error","Start_date":"10/6/2012 6:25:06 PM","InitialResponseDueDate":"10/6/2012 7:25:06 PM","Locked":"0","QValue":"$19","Status":"1","Author_ID":"71317792","Question_Text":"office/outlook for mac 2011 keeps hanging upMicrosoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0<br/><br/>Error Signature:<br/>Exception: EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP)<br/>Date/Time: 2012-10-06 17:59:38 +0000<br/>Application Name: Microsoft Outlook<br/>Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Outlook<br/>Application Signature: OPIM<br/>Application Version: 14.2.4.120824<br/>Crashed Module Name: merp<br/>Crashed Module Version: 2.2.4.120824<br/>Crashed Module Offset: 0x00003aa2<br/>Blame Module Name: Microsoft Outlook<br/>Blame Module Version: 14.2.4.120824<br/>Blame Module Offset: 0x003c900c<br/>Application LCID: 1033<br/>Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0409<br/>Crashed thread: 10","Username":"JACUSTOMER-wr0d1qwb-","No_of_Questions":"0","No_of_Accepts":"0","Last_visit":"10/6/2012 6:54:53 PM","Join_Date":"10/6/2012 6:25:00 PM","lastExpert":"","IsPress":"False","hasCustomerOptOuts":"0","RecCount":"0","OptedOut":"","Urgency":"51","AuthorHasSubscription":"False","Relisted":"0","IsAbandoned":"False","categoryName":"Microsoft Office","categoryName_Additional":"","QuestionCommissionHasAdjusted":"False","LockedBy":"-1","IsOnline":"False","QuestionLink":"/microsoft-office/77lni-office-outlook-mac-2011-keeps-hanging-upmicrosoft-error.html","WaitingForYou":"False","RequestedForYou":"False","IsChatEnabled":"True","ChangedKeyList":"","DeltaType":"A"},"12106917":{"Topic_ID":"12106917","Moved_ID":"0","subject":"test","Start_date":"10/5/2012 6:22:42 PM","InitialResponseDueDate":"10/5/2012 6:40:42 PM","Locked":"0","QValue":"$21","Status":"1","Author_ID":"69617617","Question_Text":"test","Username":"JACUSTOMER-dwbsyao6-","No_of_Questions":"4","No_of_Accepts":"1","Last_visit":"10/6/2012 11:12:19 AM","Join_Date":"7/16/2012 12:59:47 PM","lastExpert":"","IsPress":"False","hasCustomerOptOuts":"0","RecCount":"0","OptedOut":"","Urgency":"0","AuthorHasSubscription":"True","Relisted":"0","IsAbandoned":"False","categoryName":"Computer","categoryName_Additional":"","QuestionCommissionHasAdjusted":"True","LockedBy":"-1","IsOnline":"True","QuestionLink":"/computer/77hr9-test.html","WaitingForYou":"False","RequestedForYou":"False","IsChatEnabled":"True","ChangedKeyList":"","DeltaType":"A"}}'
```

I received the "InvalidCastException", Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.

I tried removing the single quotes from the start and end of the string but got the same message?

Comment: pst - I have added the actual JSON string to me question above.  The original JSON string was a formatted and stripped down version to give a summary of my problem.

Comment: I removed my -1. However, make sure to include the *actual* code used in the question as well - this helps refine/focus a question.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I take your point on board.  This was my first post and I probably rushed it a little to be honest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

(The JSON posted is invalid. The following works *after* replacing invalid `\u005C"`s with `\u005C`.)

```
string json = @"{""12112083"":{""Topic_ID"":""12112083"",""Moved_ID"":""51"",""subject"":""Due to a computer virus, many of my files are \u005CCrypted\u005C,espe"",""Start_date"":""10/6/2012 6:54:37 PM"",""InitialResponseDueDate"":""10/6/2012 7:01:37 PM"",""Locked"":""0"",""QValue"":""$10"",""Status"":""1"",""Author_ID"":""71318191"",""Question_Text"":""Due to a computer virus, many of my files are \u005CCrypted\u005C,especially my pictures.  Now my FinepixA500 camera will not upload photos to my computer (laptop).  Geek Squad could not crack the code and suggested that I contact Toshiba and have them reset the computer to its original manufacturer settings.  If I do that, I will lose all of my data.  The only thing that appears not to be working is \u005Cphoto gallery\u005C. (therefore, my camera will not upload photos anymore.....) Any suggestions?"",""Username"":""JACUSTOMER-iei7o0tr-"",""No_of_Questions"":""0"",""No_of_Accepts"":""0"",""Last_visit"":""10/6/2012 7:22:18 PM"",""Join_Date"":""10/6/2012 6:46:29 PM"",""lastExpert"":"""",""IsPress"":""False"",""hasCustomerOptOuts"":""0"",""RecCount"":""0"",""OptedOut"":"""",""Urgency"":""51"",""AuthorHasSubscription"":""False"",""Relisted"":""0"",""IsAbandoned"":""False"",""categoryName"":""Camera and Video"",""categoryName_Additional"":""Laptop"",""QuestionCommissionHasAdjusted"":""False"",""LockedBy"":""-1"",""IsOnline"":""False"",""QuestionLink"":""/video-camera-repair/77lqr-due-computer-virus-files-crypted-espe.html"",""WaitingForYou"":""False"",""RequestedForYou"":""False"",""IsChatEnabled"":""False"",""ChangedKeyList"":"""",""DeltaType"":""A""},""12111966"":{""Topic_ID"":""12111966"",""Moved_ID"":""51"",""subject"":""office/outlook for mac 2011 keeps hanging upMicrosoft Error"",""Start_date"":""10/6/2012 6:25:06 PM"",""InitialResponseDueDate"":""10/6/2012 7:25:06 PM"",""Locked"":""0"",""QValue"":""$19"",""Status"":""1"",""Author_ID"":""71317792"",""Question_Text"":""office/outlook for mac 2011 keeps hanging upMicrosoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0<br/><br/>Error Signature:<br/>Exception: EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP)<br/>Date/Time: 2012-10-06 17:59:38 +0000<br/>Application Name: Microsoft Outlook<br/>Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Outlook<br/>Application Signature: OPIM<br/>Application Version: 14.2.4.120824<br/>Crashed Module Name: merp<br/>Crashed Module Version: 2.2.4.120824<br/>Crashed Module Offset: 0x00003aa2<br/>Blame Module Name: Microsoft Outlook<br/>Blame Module Version: 14.2.4.120824<br/>Blame Module Offset: 0x003c900c<br/>Application LCID: 1033<br/>Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0409<br/>Crashed thread: 10"",""Username"":""JACUSTOMER-wr0d1qwb-"",""No_of_Questions"":""0"",""No_of_Accepts"":""0"",""Last_visit"":""10/6/2012 6:54:53 PM"",""Join_Date"":""10/6/2012 6:25:00 PM"",""lastExpert"":"""",""IsPress"":""False"",""hasCustomerOptOuts"":""0"",""RecCount"":""0"",""OptedOut"":"""",""Urgency"":""51"",""AuthorHasSubscription"":""False"",""Relisted"":""0"",""IsAbandoned"":""False"",""categoryName"":""Microsoft Office"",""categoryName_Additional"":"""",""QuestionCommissionHasAdjusted"":""False"",""LockedBy"":""-1"",""IsOnline"":""False"",""QuestionLink"":""/microsoft-office/77lni-office-outlook-mac-2011-keeps-hanging-upmicrosoft-error.html"",""WaitingForYou"":""False"",""RequestedForYou"":""False"",""IsChatEnabled"":""True"",""ChangedKeyList"":"""",""DeltaType"":""A""},""12106917"":{""Topic_ID"":""12106917"",""Moved_ID"":""0"",""subject"":""test"",""Start_date"":""10/5/2012 6:22:42 PM"",""InitialResponseDueDate"":""10/5/2012 6:40:42 PM"",""Locked"":""0"",""QValue"":""$21"",""Status"":""1"",""Author_ID"":""69617617"",""Question_Text"":""test"",""Username"":""JACUSTOMER-dwbsyao6-"",""No_of_Questions"":""4"",""No_of_Accepts"":""1"",""Last_visit"":""10/6/2012 11:12:19 AM"",""Join_Date"":""7/16/2012 12:59:47 PM"",""lastExpert"":"""",""IsPress"":""False"",""hasCustomerOptOuts"":""0"",""RecCount"":""0"",""OptedOut"":"""",""Urgency"":""0"",""AuthorHasSubscription"":""True"",""Relisted"":""0"",""IsAbandoned"":""False"",""categoryName"":""Computer"",""categoryName_Additional"":"""",""QuestionCommissionHasAdjusted"":""True"",""LockedBy"":""-1"",""IsOnline"":""True"",""QuestionLink"":""/computer/77hr9-test.html"",""WaitingForYou"":""False"",""RequestedForYou"":""False"",""IsChatEnabled"":""True"",""ChangedKeyList"":"""",""DeltaType"":""A""}}";

var jobj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var items = jobj.Children()
    .Cast<JProperty>()
    .Select(j=>new
    {
        ID=j.Name,
        Topic = (string)j.Value["Topic_ID"],
        Moved = (string)j.Value["Moved_ID"],
        Subject = (string)j.Value["subject"],
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks L.B, I have edited the question with more detail and the exception I received after trying your code sample above

Comment: @user1462387 if you fix your json(it is invalid) you will see that above coce works without any exception.

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that the "\u005C" unicode character for the backslash in the JSON might be causing the problem.  I have no control over the JSON served to me so I need to replace this somehow

Comment: @user1462387 the problem is not the `\u005C` char, it is `\u005C"` in your json

Comment: @L.B: Unable to access child value it says, exception. Your solution doesn't work

Comment: @L.B: Thanks, but my situation was slightly different and unfortunately yours didn't help me and I could rectify my errors

Answer (score 2):

Using System.Web, I have a little method that seems to make its way into every project that uses JSON for data storage:

```
private T UnpackJson<T>(object data)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string rawJSON = serializer.Serialize(data);

    var result = serializer.Deserialize<T>(rawJSON);
    return result;
}
```

...Where T is some type with elements that match the schema that you are deserializing.  For your blob that is given in the top, I'd suggest something like:

```
// Using my above method...
var x = UnpackJson<Foo[]>(blob);

public class Foo
{
    public string ID;
    public Bar SubItem;
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Topic_ID;
    public int Subject_ID;
    public string subject; 
}
```

...Note that your variables names should *totally* match the names of attributes in the JSON blob!  I certainly hope this works (note that while I use the method and know for certain that it will deserialize a blob to a class, this implementation is untested.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) - free JSON parser/serializer for .NET.

Comment: Please include a relevant example of usages given the concrete structure presented.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually using JSON.NET but it's the structure of the JSON which I am struggling to deserialize